# Change background according to Slide

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get the following:

By using Flexslider (http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/) I want to get a different background color according to which slide is loaded.

I did something like this:

```
  <?php
    $bg1="red";
    $bg2="blue";
  ?>
```

Then, in my flexslider jquery:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        start: function(slider){
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        },
        before: function(slider) {
          var current = slider.currentSlide;
          $('#container').css("background-color","<?php echo $bg?>+current");
        },
      });
    });
  </script>
```

I am trying to retrieve the value from my php variables, and put them inside the css for my container. Ok here is where I'm stuck, how do I get it to load bg1 if it's the first slide, bg2 if it's the second, and so on?

I thought I could do something like +current but it's not working... I'm sure it's something easy here-

Any help is super appreciated!

Thx!

Comment: You mean continually change between `$bg1` and `$bg2` on slide change?

Comment: yes exactly, that's what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do what I needed by using Flexslider (which has some APIs), so my final code is like:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade",
        slideshow: true,                //Boolean: Animate slider automatically
        slideshowSpeed: 6000,
        animationSpeed: 300,
        start: function(slider){
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        },
        before: function(slider) {
          animate = 'bg'+slider.animatingTo
          $('#container').addClass(animate, 1000);
          current = 'bg'+slider.currentSlide;
          $('#container').removeClass(current);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use modulus, as in..

```
$('#container').css("background-color",(current%2==0)?"<?php echo $bg1?>":"<?php echo $bg2?>");
```

Comment: this works, thanks! but would it be similar if with three or more slides and backgrounds? My issue is that i can have maybe 4 or 5 slides, and they would be associated with bg colors.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, however taking a quick look throw flexslider.js I'm relatively confident you can achieve your background scrolling inside the function slider.flexAnimate found at line 427.  This assumes you only have the slider in use at one location (or at least are OK with the background change happening for each instance of the slider).

Also, if your slider is on a constant time interval I'd like to suggest using CSS keyframe animations to loop through your 2 background options.  Here's a little example, assuming a 10 second interval:

```
@keyframes bgpulse {
  0% {background-color:  #FFFFFF;}
 100% {background-color:  #000000;}    
}
@-webkit-keyframes bgpulse {
  0% {background-color:  #FFFFFF;}
 100% {background-color:  #000000;}
}

/*Body Styles*/
body {
animation: bgpulse 10s infinite alternate;
-webkit-animation: bgpulse 10s infinite alternate;
}
```

Comment: This looks good, but I would like to be able to choose my bg dynamically (hence the php variables) and they might even be 3 or 4, according to how many slides I have. Keeping investigating... Actually if I could add the number of the current slide to the php var, and then I'd be set in think...

Comment: Also, the slider is not a constant, a user could cycle manually through it, and that's why I thought of using the 'before' handler